# Enable or disable elements in const array

Tags: d

How does one enable/disable the inclusion of elements in an const array?

```
struct country {
  const string name;
  ulong  pop;
};

static const country countries[] = [

  {"Iceland", 800},
  {"Australia", 309},
//... and so on
//#ifdef INCLUDE_GERMANY
version(include_germany){
  {"Germany", 233254},
}
//#endif
  {"USA", 3203}
];
```

In C, you can use #ifdef to enable or disable a particular element in an array,
but how would you do that in D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. One way is to append an array conditionally, using the ternary operator:

```
static const country[] countries = [
  country("Iceland", 800),
  country("Australia", 309),
] ~ (include_germany ? [country("Germany", 233254)] : []) ~ [
  country("USA", 3203)
];
```

You can also write a function which computes and returns the array, then initialize a `const` value with it. The function will be evaluated at compile-time (CTFE).

Comment: typo: include_germary. Invalid unless the germary is the lang. of the germar. The Germar, this important nation ^^

Comment: Fixed :)

Also, I should have mentioned that `include_germany` is expected to be a constant, not a version, so it should be declared using `const`/`enum`. See @BBaz' answer below to make it work with `-version`.

Comment: Yeah, I copied that part from your example. Fixed it to use proper syntax now.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile with the custom switch`-version=include_germany`. In the code you define a static bool:

```
static bool include_germany;
version(include_germany){include_germany = true;}
```

To build the array is then identical as described in the CyberShadow answer.

Comment: I think you need `const` or `enum`, not `static`.